# Regex remove sequential duplicates from a space-delimited string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to remove (from a string) only the duplicates that occur sequentially.  That is, given the string "1 2 3 3 2 1" only one of the 3's should be removed (i.e. "1 2 3 2 1").  I really thought I had it figured out.  And then, during testing, I found a case where it didn't work.  I've tried every combination I could think of, to no avail.  Surely it's something simple, as it's not a hard match to do (except for me, obviously).

Following is some Javascript to illustrate the problem.  The first testVal string is handled correctly.  The commented-out testVal string is not handled correctly.

```
// The following string should reduce to: MTC MTCA MTC ORD MTC (it does).
var testVal = "MTC MTC MTCA MTC MTC MTC ORD MTC";

// The following string should reduce to: MTC (it does not.  Result = MTC MTC).
// The string MTC MTC MTC MTC also only reduces to MTC MTC, so I'm thinking
// it's a whitespace issue.
// var testVal = "MTC MTC";

while (/\b(\s*\w+\s*)\b\1/.test(testVal)) {
    testVal = testVal.replace(/\b(\s*\w+\s*)\b\1/g,'$1');
}

alert(testVal1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are including the whitespace as part of the word to be matched twice. Try

```
/\b(\w+)\s+\1\b/
```

Comment: Sheesh. That was it. Thanks for the quick response @Neil!